# Obfuscate python

Tags: python, python-3.x, обфускация

Есть сурс с несколькими импортами, нужно сделать его анридбл для человека
Есть какие нибудь инструменты для этого?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [base64.b64encode(bytes_like)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/base64.html)

Answer (score 0):

Варианты решения

- Встроенными средствами 
  *python -OO -m py_compile*
- Pyminifier

  www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-ways-to-obfuscate-Python-code
  https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/